# Why is the dynamically allocated memory released multiple times?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

I use mutex and static variable to make sure the dynamically allocated memory to be released only once. But they are still released multiple times. Why?

Thanks.

I have read some threads saying it's not necessary to explicitly release static pointers. But It would be good to understand why that happens.

```
// use C++-20
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

class A {

private:
    static atomic_int *a;//=NULL;
    static std::mutex mutex_;
public:
    A() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (!a) {
            a = new atomic_int[10]();
            std::cout << "creation A..." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ~A() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (a) {
            delete[] a;
            //delete a;
            a = NULL;
            std::cout << "deletion A..." << std::endl;
        }

    }

    A(A &t) {
        cout << "copy..." << endl;
    }


};

atomic_int *A::a = NULL;
std::mutex A::mutex_;

class B {
private:
    static A *a;
    static std::mutex mutex_;

public:
    B() {

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (!a) {
            a = new A();
            std::cout << "creation B ..." << std::endl;
        }

    }

    ~B() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (a) {
            cout << "Delete B" << endl;
            delete a;
            a = NULL;
        }
    }

    void run() {
        std::cout << "Hello from B" << std::endl;
    }

    thread take_action() {
        return thread([this] { run(); });
    }
};

A *B::a = NULL;
std::mutex B::mutex_;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    vector<B> b;
    vector<std::thread> b_thread;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        b.push_back(B());

    }

//
//    B b1, b2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        b[i].run();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i) {
        b_thread.push_back(b[i].take_action());

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b_thread.size(); ++i) {
        b_thread[i].join();
    }

//    b1.run();

//    b2.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Hello World
creation A...
creation B ...
Delete B
deletion A...
creation A...
creation B ...
Delete B
deletion A...
creation A...
creation B ...
Delete B
deletion A...
Hello from B
Hello from B
Hello from B
Hello from B
Hello from B
Hello from B
```

Comment: In `~A()` the memory is freed and `a` is set to `NULL` leaving a dangling pointer for any other `A` instances out there. The next time an `A` is created it checks if `a` is `NULL` and since it is allocates memory again so the next time an `A` is destroyed the memory is freed, and so on.

Comment: You may want to add `A& operator=(A& src)` and add appropriate print statements to show a copy assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you use such codes

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        b.push_back(B());

    }
```

You will create three B objects, they are temporary variables, and they will destruct after `push_back` execute, so you allocate A pointer and delete it three times.

Comment: This is correct.  And because there's no copy constructor defined, the default doesn't output anything and is invisible.

Comment: So because A::a is static and all instances share the same one, does that mean a[] is already deleted after the copy construction and it's actually a memory violation if it's accessed?

Comment: Yes, because you don't create a new B object after one B object destruct, the A::a is delete. In `~A()`, A::a is free. If you want to use static pointer, I think you can use a static count variable, when B is construct(including copy, default constructor and so on), the count increase and when `~B()`, it decreases. The method can guarantee B::a is not null when there are active B objects @qwert